# Saving Custom Class to File using Serializable (Android)

Tags: java, android, serialization, save, instances

Hello I got a really weird problem...
I am using the Interface "Serializable" to save the Root Object of my Class to file.
Furthermore I am storing other instances of Classes like a "Hero" etc. in it.
Saving and Loading seems to be no problem....until I clear the RAM using Task Manager or Ram Booster and try to load my Data.... The initial Root Object is loaded, but every Object that is not directly initialized in my Root class (e.g "Hero myHero;" ) is null again... So I receive a null pointer exception...
I save my root object in onPause() and onStop()
and heres the Code for my save and load class

```
public static void saveToStorage(Context context, Root root)
{
    try
    {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsoluteFile(), "save.bin")));
        oos.writeObject(root);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();    
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static Object loadClassFile(File f)
{
    try
    {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        Object o = ois.readObject();
        return o;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Do the objects your root object contains also implement Serializable? Could you post the source? It sounds like you're only serialising the references to the other objects, so of course when you clear your RAM the objects referred to by the serialised object no longer exist.